# Is there a way to add in column for Week number depending on a date column?

Tags: sql, string, date, amazon-redshift

I was wondering if it is possible in SQL to read in a date column and based on that date create a new column and automatically have the Week number as well. For example today is 4/7/2020 , so the query would have Week 15 populated for that?

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkx1D.png)

In the picture the week column would ideally be populated beside 'datestr'.

Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASTEf.png)

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, postgresql...? Date functions are highly database-specific.

Comment: Yes Sunday through Monday and Week 1 - 53. The Database is redshift

Comment: [DATE_PART](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_PART_function.html) should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `extract`. I am not 100% sure if weeks in Redshift start from Sunday or Monday, but you can adjust the interval to test the edge cases.

```
select datestr, extract(week from datestr + interval '1 day') as weeknum
from your_table
```

Comment: I posted some pics for reference. This makes sense, I also tried this and I got an error, so I'm not understanding the issue

Comment: @PhillipLe You are getting that that error because you can't use your calculated column datestr as an input to a another function in the same select. Either use a sub-select or nest the calculation of datestr inside the extract/date_part function. If that solves your problem, consider accepting one of the answers because we answered your question as you originally intended.

Answer (score 1):

In redshift, you can use `date_part()` with the `w` specifier to get the week number of a date or timestamp:

```
select t.*, date_part(w, datestr) week_number from mytable t
```

Note that weeks starts on Monday in Redshift. If you want the week to start on Sunday:

```
select t.*, date_part(w, datestr + interval '1' day) week_number from mytable t
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added some more pics above to reference, when attempting this, I Originally the column is in milliseconds which I convert into date, now using this I was trying to get the week